# showing child categories database issue

Tags: magento-enterprise, category-tree

i have a real strange one here. i have 3 environments a dev a stage and a production.
exact same codebase on all three.
on my dev and production boxes my categories on the left hand nav display exactly as they should.
showing only the current categories in the branch.
however on the stage box the left hand nav shows all the child categories as well.

Ive swapped the databases on stage and dev and the problem followed the database, so its a DB issue, but what? the level values in catalog_category_entity are correct i have checked.

where else should i look?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i just needed to truncate the catalog_category_flat_* tables and the catalog_category_product_index table, flush redis and rebuild my indexes and away we go ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair the database using magento database repair tool.

### Database Repair Tool

Help to compare two databases(stage & Dev).

[Database Repair Tool](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html/)